# Markdown2 how to get "extras" working?

Tags: python, markdown

It is unclear to me how to get syntax hilighting with python's markdown2 library.

````
text = """```if True: 
print "hello"```"""
markdown2.markdown(text,extras=['fenced-code-blocks'])
u'<p><code>if True:\nprint "hello"</code></p>\n'
````

It seems the "extra" fenced-code-blocks is not working as the output is the same as without it

```
markdown2.markdown(text)
u'<p><code>if True:\nprint "hello"</code></p>\n'
```

Whereas the output should have all the span classes for a css file to highlight, like

```
<pre><code><span class="k">if</span> <span class="bp">True</span>, etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the problem is that markdown2 doesn't know which language your code snippit is and so won't know how to parse it/add syntax highlighting. You'll need to modify your Markdown to be more explicit:

````
import markdown2

text = """
```python
if True: 
    print "hello"
```
"""

print markdown2.markdown(text,extras=['fenced-code-blocks'])
````

This produces the following output:

```
<div class="codehilite"><pre><code><span class="k">if</span> <span class="bp">True</span><span class="p">:</span>
    <span class="k">print</span> <span class="s">&quot;hello&quot;</span>
</code></pre></div>
```

Note that you must also have the [pygments](http://pygments.org/) library installed, and must provide one of the following [CSS files](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css) for the final HTML file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how I missed this.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to add language guess to this? (just like it works on SO)